# Post-route Middleware not triggered Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I am trying to add a middleware after the app so that I can add timestamps and other information to my API calls. I have properly set up my routes as it reaches my middleware properly, but when I reach the middle ware, an error is thrown which is:

> Call to a member function put() on a non-object

And my middleware has the following code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $response = $next($request);
    if($response->headers->get('content-type') == 'application/json')
    {
        $collection = $response->original;
        //dd( $collection );
        $collection->put('timestamp', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $response->setContent($collection);
    }

    return $response;
}
```

I have tried to dd( $collection ), but it returns the objects that should be returned, so I have no idea what's wrong. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: When you did dd() in the collection, what type was it? Apparently not an object

Comment: We need more information in order to help here. Can you run a get_class on both the `$response` object and the `$response->original`? When I try this in Laravel 5.1, `$response->original` doesn't exist for json responses (` return Response::json([])`), so it throws a fatal. `$response->original` is an `Illuminate\View\View` for a standard view response in Laravel. So can't really help without more info.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo apparently it is returned as an array:

`
array:2 [
  1 => Entity {#235
    
  }
  2 => Entity {#228
    
  }
]
`

Comment: Then just do $collection['timestamp'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: @Ben : When I get_class $response, it returns: "Illuminate\Http\Response"  while $response->original throws an exception "get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given"

Answer (score 0):

From @jedrzej.kurylo's suggestion, I made the following changes :

```
    $response = $next($request);
    if($response->headers->get('content-type') == 'application/json')
    {
        $collection = array();
        $collection['timestamp'] = Carbon::now();
        $collection['data'] = $response->original;
        $response->setContent($collection);
    }
    return $response;
```

It appears that $response->original returns an array instead of an object consisting of the objects for the response.
Thanks SO!